# Split variable to line and create a new variable

Tags: bash

I have in a variable with results, I need to every line a new variable. So have several times the same.

I have in the variable `$results` lines among themselves. I want for every line a new variable. I hope it's so better.

```
Input from $results:
Found1
Found2
Found3
Found4
Found5
etc...

Output:
w1 Found1
w2 Found1
w3 Found1
w4 Found1
w5 Found1
w1 Found2
w2 Found2
w3 Found2
w4 Found2
w5 Found2
w1 Found3
w2 Found3
w3 Found3
w4 Found3
w5 Found3
```

>

```
zahl=$(echo "$results" | wc -l)

if [ "$zahl" -ge "5" ];then
echo "over 5";
exit 1
else
for z in $results
do
w1=$(echo $z | cut -d" " -f1)
w2=$(echo $z | cut -d" " -f2)
w3=$(echo $z | cut -d" " -f3)
w4=$(echo $z | cut -d" " -f4)
w5=$(echo $z | cut -d" " -f5)
echo "$w1"
echo "$w2"
echo "$w3"
echo "$w4"
echo "$w5"
done
fi
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking...

Comment: i have in the variable $results lines among themselves. I want for every line a new variable. I hope its so better

Comment: Please provide sample input (what does `$results` contains?) and expected output so that we're able to reproduce and help you.

Comment: i have edit on the top

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to use multiple variables, is an array not suitable for your case?

Answer (score 0):

```
zahl=$(echo "$results" | wc -l)

if [ "$zahl" -gt "5" ];then
  echo "over 5";
  exit 1
else
  for v in w1 w2 w3 w4 w5; do
    IFS= read -r "$v" || { unset "$v"; break; }
  done <<< "$results"
fi
```

If there are only, say, 3 lines of input, then `w4` and `w5` will not be set.

Answer (score -1):

I'm stretching here, but I think what you want is something like this:

```
i=1
for z in $results; do
    eval "w$i=\"\$z\""
    ((i++))
done

echo "$w1"
echo "$w2"
echo "$w3"
echo "$w4"
echo "$w5"
```

This will set `w1` to `Found1`, `w2` to `Found2` etc.

Comment: Do not use `eval`.

Comment: @chepner, it's language feature as any other. I would agree that it might hurt you when used improperly, but saying "don't use it" is just plain wrong.

Comment: Do you know what the contents of `$results` will be? If not, then, yes, it is wrong to use `eval` here.

Comment: @chepner, would you provide an example contents of `$results` which will lead to issues with `eval`?

Comment: Ok, in this case, `eval` is *probably* safe, but it is still unnecessary. Use `declare` instead: `declare "w$i=$z". Using `eval` is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: There's also the issue of assuming that each line of `results` is free from whitespace or glob characters, which isn't a safety issue but does not guaranteed that each `w` variable is assigned a complete line from the results. (See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).)

Comment: Thanks, aware of that last one. Was simplifying for the sample input provided.